# Performance tuning based on number of part files created in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following are phases of my job :

1. Phase 1 - Do some computation and persist the temp data into file.There will be multiple temp dataframes persisted and read in the flow.
2. Phase 2 - Read the temp data and do some other computation and store it to the final data file.

**NOTE**: I am persisting multiple temp files as I cannot hold them in memory since the data is huge.(84 million rows , 2 million distinct primary key kindoff value )

I use coleasce(n) or repartition(n) , where n is a large number eg: 200. Now this leads to 200 files created in the output for each of the temp data that I'm persisting. I know coleasce/repartition is a costly job for write performance. But i do get better parallelism when i use n=200 than when n=50. This is all with respect to write.

Now , this temp data is going to be read by next processes , So will n=200 be better or n=50 ?

Also, I am aware that the parent partition number (n) will be the base for the next write operation and so on.

Qs:

1. When to use coleasce(no shuffle) and when to use repartition (shuffle) ?
2. The partition value to be used and why?
3. What strategy should I follow for getting a better performance?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use coalesce when the size of the output files is unlikely to be skewed (1 files 2GB, rest 0GB). Repartitioning is most useful when you want to balance the work among executors so each partition is similarly sized.

2) set your output partitions based on assigned value to write and read time. For example, have a large number of partitions (smaller files) for writing and reading both once (re intermediate output), but set the partitions lower (larger files) when writing once reading many times (WORM for using parquet as analytics). The more partitions, the more concurrent tasks that can be done at once.

3) try the different approaches if you can and measure the writing and reading times; determine the tradeoffs that best suit your use case.

It's a lot like compression algorithms where some can compress fast (eg LZO), others store with minimal footprint (eg BZip2) and others decompress fast (eg Snappy).